# close on click push notification

Tags: javascript, push-notification, service-worker

how can I make the push notification close on click in my service worker?

```
self.addEventListener('push', (e) => {
    let data = e.data.json();
    const options = {
        body: data.body,
        icon: 'images/notifIcon.png',
    data: {
        url: data.url
    }
}
    e.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification(data.title, options));
});
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(e) {
    e.waitUntil(clients.openWindow(e.notification.data.url))
});
```

I wanted to add close() in notificationclick addEventListener but I don't know how to do it.